# Links getting cut off in outlook

Tags: html, microsoft-outlook

I have long hyperlinks. These get cut of in outlook to just the first line. Shortening them is not an option. How do I get the entire link to show up on Outlook?

I tried doing it again in word. But then it inserts additional garbage values in the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing the link between < and > to contain the URL like this. Another way to 
go would be to replace the spaces with %20 which is the equivalent of a 
space.

When you mean shortening them is not an option.. Do you mean, you can't use bit.ly or another shortening service?

Or do you mean that you can't create a shorter anchor text that is shorter and keep the URL of the hyperlink the same?

Comment: I cannot use a shortened url with the help of tinyurl or other such services.

Comment: So, create some text for the hyperlink. Highlight the text, right click and create a hyperlink with the full URL that you need. - Basically, making it an anchor text hyperlink.